# on click triggering of fb share dialog box not working

Tags: facebook

I have one online treasure hunt website.When a user enter a correct answer it will show a page which has a continue button. When we click that continue button a facebook share dialog box will appear. The onclick function for that button is  as follows.

```
<div class="row" >

        <div class="text-center">

            <?php if($result==TRUE): ?>

            <a onclick="FB.ui({
     method: 'share', 
     href: '',
     quote: 'Successfully Completed Level <?php echo $level-1 ?> . An Exciting Online Treasure Hunt',
     hashtag: '',

}, function(response){
    location.href ='<?php echo base_url() ?>';
});" class="buttonfb btn btn-lg btn-success" role="button">Continue</a>

            <?php else: ?>

            <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>" class="buttonfb buttontryagain btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button">Try Again</a>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div></div></div>
```

Here it will trigger a fb share dialog box which makes it able for user to share his achievement on fb. But the error is that when the dialog box for share appears an error message is written in dialog box. It is as follows

> Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

This is my script

```
<script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : 'here i set my app id',
              xfbml      : true,
              version    : 'v2.8'
            });
            FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
          };

          (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

         </script>
```

[image]

I already have added app domains and URL correctly in my Facebook app. Also, I have a login with Facebook button in my home page. The login with Facebook button is working fine, but the share dialog box shows this error.

Please help me.

Comment: why opening a share box on a button that says "continue"? that does not make any sense...and it looks like you require the user to share it, even though he could just cancel the dialog. make a separate share button instead. also, just a side note: you should really create a function and call that one in onclick, never seen anyone putting the whole function call in the onclick attribute, that´s just weird...

Comment: about the error itself: did you try using the correct url in the href parameter? don´t just leave it empty.

Comment: how the page is fucntioning is that@luschn

when we click continue the share dialog box will come.and if he press ok it will be shared to fb.Else if he close the dialog box he will be directed to next level.I gave onclick on my continue because many users will just click continue and ignore the share button if i keep a seperate button for share.

Comment: @luschn tried with my url..not working

Comment: "when we click continue the share dialog box will come" - that´s what i mean, very bad user experience to show a dialog for shaing when you actually press continue...just saying. "else, less users will share it" is not a good excuse for bad UX ;)

Comment: i´d even say it´s not allowed, beause it would be "incentivizing" - which is definitely not allowed

Comment: ok.i can give a seperate button.but what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: add a screenshot of the relevant app settings please